# Double number's multiplication with out precision and commas

Tags: java

i have an array, a double array like...

```
Double my_array = new Double[] {6272640.0, 43560.0, 4840.0, 0.0015625, 4046856422.400000095, 40468564.223999999, 4046.856422400, 0.004046856, 1.0, 0.404685642};
```

and in my program i want to multiply each of that elements with some integer values...
which i accept through a variable n.

i had done it in my program as...

```
for(int 1=0;i<my_array.length;i++)
{
my_array[i] = n*my_array[i];
}
```

when i try to print the result, i gets value as exponentials...
like, 3.23E etc etc......

I need the result as double value up to 8 decimal points...

What should i do to get it

Comment: "i try to print the result": How do you print the result?

Comment: what does string-to-double means here if you multiply with int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed my double array to String array, like

```
String my_array[];
my_array = new String[] {"1.006944444","6.45160645160", "0.00000326701", "0.0076001595"};

// then used my for loop like

BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(n);
for(int 1=0;i<my_array.length;i++)
{
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(Double.parseDouble(my_array[i]));
BigDecimal result = b1.multiply(b2);
System.out.println(result.doubleValue);
}
```

just check it yourself. as i had just described the logic, my for loop had much more to do..

Answer (score 5):

You should format your output.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html (general explanation)
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html (formatting symbols)

```
double yourDouble = 0.1234567890;
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00000000");
System.out.println(myFormatter.format(yourDouble));
```

Should print "0.12345678".

Comment: Also take a look at String#format (Java's version of printf), which has a more concise API.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("###.########"); // define here how much you want precision
for(int i=0;i<my_array.length;i++) 
  System.out.println(df.format(my_array[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
String str = String.valueOf(double d);
```

solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
double value = X.XX;
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.'); // if needed
symbols.setGroupingSeparator('\u0020'); // if needed
decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(8); // or any other
decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(8); // or any other
decimalFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN); // if needed
return decimalFormat.format(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this site...

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1307290